# Are a trigger's actions limited by the user permissions of the user whose actions trigger the trigger?

Tags: trigger, permissions

I have a trigger on Opportunities to automatically assign certain opportunities to certain owners in specific contexts.  If the user who edits the opportunity doesn't have permission to change the owner, will that prevent the trigger from changing the owner?  If so, how can I override that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, triggers run in system context.

To utilize permissions, you should pass your logic to a helper class that uses the 'with sharing' keyword.

There's a good article on trigger design [here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers)

Comment: [This post](http://www.tgerm.com/2011/03/trigger-insufficient-access-cross.html) also talks about the scenario of a trigger calling a class [with sharing](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm)

Comment: With sharing wouldn't be ideal for a trigger scenario, because that would involve a recursive DML operation. Instead, you'd query UserRecordAccess to determine if the user can change ownership. Since it's restrictive to use though, you'd probably have to also prevent the user from editing in bulk.

Comment: @BarCotter that was very informative, thanks for that share